# Convert JSON string from database to PHP array problems

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to convert this JSON string into a PHP array. The JSON string is stored in my database and I have already retrieved it.

```
{
  "users": "user1, user2"
}
```

I need to convert the above JSON string into an array like the following but dynamically.

```
$myArray = array("user1", "user2")
```

This is my code:

```
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $json = $row['json'];
  $decode = json_decode($json);
  $list = $decode->users;
  $myArray = explode(',', $list);
```

This code doesn't work in my program but when I print the array with print_r it looks identical to if I print $myArray from the nondynamic string. This is a concern because the nondynamic string works.

Comment: show one of those dynamic strings

Comment: Why are you storing it as a comma-separated list? JSON can represent arrays, so why not make it an array before encoding it as JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separator between the usernames is comma+space, you're just using comma when you explode, so the second and following usernames are getting a space at the beginning. Try:

```
$myArray = explode(', ', $list);
```

I recommend that you change the JSON structure so you store an actual array, rather than a comma-separated list.

```
{
    "users": ["user1", "user2"]
}
```

Even better would be to change your database structure so the users are in a real table, rather than being wrapped in JSON. This would allow you to perform queries that search for users easily and efficiently.

Comment: I do have users in a real table but this JSON is to show a user's friends. Thank you, adding the space after the comma fixed it..

Comment: @DanielZam You should have a `friends` table, so you can do things like `Tell me all the users who have Joe as a friend`.

Comment: Thank you, I will consider doing this. I am still learning PHP and MySQL and the functionality that I have so far is all that I need for now.

Comment: So if I do what you recommended is this what my code should look like?  $myArray = json_decode($json);